# Where is the "Risk and Health Assessment" for SP 2013

Tags: 2013

I used this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13150 but while back. Is there a similar tool for SP 2013 ? If yes, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we used the RAP tool from MSFT but it was paid tool not free. You can check more details here [Premier Proactive Services](https://services.premier.microsoft.com/assess?Culture=en-US&CultureAutoDetect=true).

You have to contact MSFT for it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft did not create an SPRAP tool for public usage. Instead, they direct people to Microsoft to purchase the RAP As A Service from the [Premier Proactive Services](https://services.premier.microsoft.com/?Culture=en-US&CultureAutoDetect=true). You can get additional information about this service through your TAM.

Comment: cool. thanks for the info. I will contact them as we are premier customer.